# Laravel Mix error Module parse failed: Unexpected character ''

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix, pkcs#11

I get a Laravel-mix error Module parse failed: Unexpected character ''. So in my Laravel/Vue project, I installed the following library.

```
npm i pkcs11js file-loader url-loader
```

However, when I run...

```
npm run watch
```

I get the following error.

> ERROR in ./node_modules/pkcs11js/build/Release/pkcs11.node 1:0
> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> (Source code omitted for this binary file)

I don't understand how can I modify my webpack.config.js that is this:

```
const { assertSupportedNodeVersion } = require('../src/Engine');
module.exports = async () => {
    process.noDeprecation = true;
    assertSupportedNodeVersion();
    const mix = require('../src/Mix').primary;
    require(mix.paths.mix());

    await mix.installDependencies();
    await mix.init();

    return mix.build();
};
```

May anyone suggest how to?

Comment: Take a look on Laravel Mix docs, they explain how to change the webpack config:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#custom-webpack-configuration